# cannot figure out MySQL ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I am pretty new to MySQL...so I am sure this is probably an easy fix for someone...I've tried tutorials and other help topics, but can't figure out why it isn't working.

I have a data table with an auto incrementing index. I want to select the last 2 rows of the table. This is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM tburg_golf ORDER BY 'index' DESC LIMIT 2
```

For some reason though, it gives me the first two rows. I've tried removing the limit, changing DESC to ASC...everything I can think of.

If curious, this is part of a larger piece of code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tburg_golf ORDER BY 'index' DESC LIMIT 2");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $day = $row['day'];
    $time = $row['time'];
    $icon = $row['icon'];
    $forecast = $row['forecast'];
    $updated = $row['updated'];

echo $date.$day.$time.$icon.$forecast.$updated.'<p>';
}
```

Comment: Is your auto-increment column called index? What if you remove the quotes around 'index'?

Comment: Removing the quotes will cause an error because `index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You need to replace your quotes by backquotes `

Comment: So right. Definitely a brainfart on my part.

Comment: Yes- the problem was I had single-quotes and not the back-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ordering by `'index'` which is a *string constant*. Column names are instead surrounded by `

Provided your auto incrementing column is actually called `index`, this will work;

```
SELECT * FROM tburg_golf ORDER BY `index` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Ordering by `'index'` will sort every line by the same string, which basically will give you rows in random order.

Comment: Ohh...I thought the ` were single-quotes. Thank you so much for clearing that up. It works great now! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tburg_golf ORDER BY `index` DESC LIMIT 2
```

If you type `'index'` MySQL will ORDER BY the string `'index'`, which is the same for all tuples, instead of your column `index`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a field in the table called "index"?

If there is I believe the word index is a reserved word in MySQL which is why it might not work. Either rename the field or wrap it with ` instead of ' e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tburg_golf ORDER BY `index` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Ohh...I thought the ` were single-quotes. Thank you so much for clearing that up. It works great now! :)